# Why is the image displayed only after restarting the application?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring + Thymeleaf, I load an image, everything loads fine, everything renders fine in html, but the image itself doesn't appear, it ONLY appears after restarting the application.
Even pages reboot doesn't help.

My html:

```
  <div class="container post-wrapper">

    <div class="post" th:data-item="${image.getId()}" th:each="image : ${images.getItems()}">
      <img th:src="${image.getPathToSmallImage()}" th:alt="${image.getNameGame()}"
           th:data-img="${image.getPathToBigImage()}">
      <p th:text="${image.getNameGame()}"></p>
      <span class="like" th:classappend="${image.isMeLiked()} ? liked : '' " th:text="${image.getNumLikes()}"></span>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Youtube video demonstrating the bug:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgE5i8yJ5T8

Comment: This might have something to do with caching, probably in browser... Have you tried force updating the page after loading image? Also not really a good idea to try and serve images straight from server's file system via straight link. I would load image as a file using java and then return it using Spring - that would make it easier to track a problem if it will keep happening. А ещё I hope that isn't your real email in the video, I wouldn't share it like that :)

Comment: @PavelPolyakoff, This is my email, but it's not used anywhere, so don't worry:)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.